# Count Business Days excluding start date and include end date with busday_count

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Is there any way how to exclude StartDate and include EndDate, I used busday_count and this definitely include start and exclude end date?

```
np.busday_count('2020-05-06', '2020-05-17')
```

out: 8 correct out should be 7 because first day is Wed and we don't want to count it and next week to Fri which counted in

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To exclude the first day:

You can increment both the start and end date by 1:

```
>>> start = np.datetime64('2020-05-06')
>>> end = np.datetime64('2020-05-17')
>>> np.busday_count(start,end)
8
>>> np.busday_count(start+1,end+1)
7
```

The first increment excludes the start date, and the second increment includes the end date in the calculation.

---

To exclude the first business day:

```
>>> start = np.datetime64('2020-05-10')
>>> end = np.datetime64('2020-05-21')
>>> max(np.busday_count(start, end)-1+np.is_busday(end),0)
8
```

Here, you subtract one since you always want to exclude the first business day, and add one if the end is also a business day. Finally, a max with zero is taken to avoid the case when there is no business day, which would have given -1 as the result otherwise.

Comment: hm, I think this won't help because if StartDate is Sunday and when I increase by 1 it will be Monday for example 5/10 - 5/21
I should increment to 5/11 - 5/22 and I got 9 days what is incorrect because have to count days as 5/10 - 5/21 and Monday shouldn't be counted then Tue is 1. ... 8. is Thursday 5/21

Comment: So do you mean you want to exclude the first business day, instead of the start date?

Comment: example 5/1 to 5/16... returned 11 days I want to exclude start date and it should be 10

excluded 5/1

Comment: Right, but in your previous comment you want to exclude 5/10 as well as 5/11. So do you exclude the first date, irrespective of whether it is a business day, or the first business day, whenever it happens?

Comment: exactly, I want to exclude first working day whenewer it comes... if start day is Sunday I want to exclude Monday...

Comment: Updated my answer.